# When Ng-click do ng-show on the clicked element in a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-show

I am trying to have a element show certain text during a load.  The issue that I run into is the elements are repeated in the ng-repeat.  When I click on one they all switch vs. just that element.  I am not sure how to just target one.

```
<div ng-repeat="session in importableMeetings">
    <a ng-click="importMeeting(session.sessionId)" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
        <span ng-show="loadingBtn">Loading...</span>
        <span ng-show="!loadingBtn">Import &raquo;</span>
    </a>
</div>

$scope.importMeeting = function (meetingId) {
          $scope.loadingBtn = true;

          .......

        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't use `session.loadingBn` for some reason, then you can use:

```
<a ng-click="importMeeting(session); loadingBtn = !loadingBtn">
    <span ng-show="loadingBtn">Loading...</span>
    <span ng-show="!loadingBtn">Import</span>
</a>
```

Every instance inside an ng-repeat creates it's own scope. So even though they all will be called `loadingBtn` the click will only alter the one instance of loadingBtn.

Answer (score 2):

You are binding all your `ng-repeat` items to the same value. In order to do it separately you will need to bind each item to its own value. I would do this by setting `loadingBtn` on each of the `importableMeetings` items (defaulting to false). For example, inside the link:

```
<a ng-click="importMeeting(session)">
    <span ng-show="session.loadingBtn">Loading...</span>
    <span ng-show="!session.loadingBtn">Import</span>
</a>
```

Then inside your controller:

```
$scope.importMeeting = function(session){
    // do what you were originally doing with your session.sessionId

    // set the bool
    session.loadingBtn = true;
};
```

Note that you now pass the entire `session` object (not just the id) to the function, allowing you to alter its properties.